# Is it safe to restart an Akka seed node?

Tags: akka

I have an Akka cluster having 2 seed nodes running on well-known (stable) IPs.

From time to time it may be necessary to restart one of the seeds for maintenance.

Is it "safe" (ie won't cause cluster fragmentation) to restart one of the seeds as long as at least one of the two is running at all times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is safe. The seed nodes are used as entry points to the cluster known by any node that wants to join (instead of a single, static master). As far as one of them are running, it is possible to join the cluster.